# How do i call function that already declared in angularjs controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have already defined a function in angularjs controller. But if I call it from somewhere in the same controller it's not working.

### controller.js

```
function ManageProductController($http, $scope, $mdDialog, $document, $location, $localStorage)
{
     var vm = this;
     vm.uid = $localStorage._id;
                
        vm.purchased = '';
        $scope.Types = [{code:1, type:'Available Items'}, {code:2, type:'Purchased Items'}, {code:3, type:'Guest Contributed'}, {code:4, type:'Full List'}];
        
        $scope.update();

                
        $scope.update = function() {
            if($scope.selectedCode == 1){
                vm.purchased = "yes";
            }else if($scope.selectedCode == 2){
                vm.purchased = "";
            }else{
                vm.purchased = "no";
            }
                                    
     $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/manage-product',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {userId:vm.uid, code:vm.purchased}
        }).success(function(res) {
            //$scope.productlist = res;
            //console.log(vm.result);
            
            vm.result = res.result;
            vm.count=vm.result.length;
            //console.log(vm.result);

            if(vm.count == 0){
                vm.showMessage = true;
            } else {
                vm.result=res.result;   
                vm.showMessage = false; 
                
            }
            
            //console.log(vm.result);
            //vm.docs=res.docs;
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('here');
        });
    };
  }
```

In the above code `$scope.update();` is not working. I have searched so many things in google but they have called in the same way but in my case it's not working. I don't know where am i wrong.

Comment: do you mean `$scope.update();` ? you call it before you declare it

Comment: yes, that was the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As @svarog said you have the call to the function before the declaration of it, so try this.

```
function ManageProductController($http, $scope, $mdDialog, $document, $location, $localStorage)
{
   var vm = this;
   vm.uid = $localStorage._id;
   vm.purchased = '';

   $scope.Types = [{code:1, type:'Available Items'}, {code:2, type:'Purchased Items'}, {code:3, type:'Guest Contributed'}, {code:4, type:'Full List'}];

   $scope.update = function() {
        if($scope.selectedCode == 1){
            vm.purchased = "yes";
        }else if($scope.selectedCode == 2){
            vm.purchased = "";
        }else{
            vm.purchased = "no";
        }
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/manage-product',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {userId:vm.uid, code:vm.purchased}
        }).success(function(res) {
        //$scope.productlist = res;
        //console.log(vm.result);
        vm.result = res.result;
        vm.count=vm.result.length;
        //console.log(vm.result);

        if(vm.count == 0){
            vm.showMessage = true;
        } else {
            vm.result=res.result;   
            vm.showMessage = false; 
        }
        //console.log(vm.result);
        //vm.docs=res.docs;
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('here');
        });
    };
    $scope.update();
}
```

Comment: yes it's okay. But it doesn't going to  ` if($scope.selectedCode == 1){
            vm.purchased = "yes";` and it directly goes to ` vm.purchased = "no";`. What should i do now?

Comment: i fixed the issue, Thank you